# Get and manipulate ffmpeg volume detect output in bat file

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have a bat file which runs the volumedetect filter:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Users\Nate\Videos\VideoClips\1080p-47243316.mp4 -filter:a volumedetect -f null /dev/null
```

Is it possible to capture all this output text it sends to cmd, and manipulate it to the point of storing say, the mean_volume into a variable?

Volumedetect output example:

[image: volumedetect output example]

Comment: Are you interested in all of these statistics, or only particular ones?

Comment: @llogan In particular, I would like to read/access the dB values for "mean_volume" and "max_volume"!

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to store the output of the volumedetect command into a file ...

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4 -filter:a volumedetect -f null nul 2>analysis.txt
```

... then to read the mean_volume value from it

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a In ('FindStr /C:"mean_volume:" analysis.txt') Do (
    For /F "tokens=1" %%b In ("%%a") Do (
        Set vMeanVol=%%b
        Set vVol=!vMeanVol:~1!
    )
)
```

The `vMeanVol` variable contains the raw value.
The `vVol` variable contains `vMeanVol` inverted and thus can be used to increase the volume using the `volume` ffmpeg filter.

**Explanation :**

`SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` enables the use of `Set %Var:~N%`

`FindStr` finds the line containing "mean_volume:"
e.g. [Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 00000180278db140] mean_volume: -21.3 dB

`For /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a` splits the line according ":" delimiter and stores the second part in `%%a`
e.g. " -21.3 dB"

`For /F "tokens=1" %%b` splits %%a according space/tab delimiter and stores the first part in %%b
e.g "-21.3"

`Set vMeanVol=%%b` stores %%b in vMeanVol

`Set vVol=!vMeanVol:~1!` gets the value of vMeanVol starting at the 2nd character (index 1), skipping the minus sign.
e.g "21.3"